# How to install python debug symbols for GDB on amazon linux AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am running into problems on my EC2 box running Python in an elastic-beanstalk container. In order to debug the problem, I need to attach a debugger to it and debug python with python symbols.

When I attach GDB to the process, I get this error:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python...(no debugging symbols found)...done. 
Attaching to program: /usr/bin/python, process 31238
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols
from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/ld-2.12.so.debug...done. done. Loaded
symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 0x00007ffec3759a63 in ?? ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install
python-2.6-2.23.amzn1.noarch
```

However, when I run debug-info install python-2.6-2.23.amzn1.noarch, it doe

```
[root@1.2.3.4]# debuginfo-install python-2.6-2.23.amzn1.noarch
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd
enabling amzn-main-debuginfo
enabling amzn-updates-debuginfo
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-main-debuginfo: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates-debuginfo: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-main-debuginfo                                                                                                                                               | 1.9 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates-debuginfo                                                                                                                                            | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: 1:python-2.6-2.23.amzn1.noarch
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

Any idea how to get these symbols on the box?

Comment: `yum repolist all`?

Comment: I got an answer from amazon support. The default AMI has debug package install disabled. See my answer below on how to enable it.

Answer (score 5):

As per amazon support:

The Amazon Linux images all have the repository for debuginfo disabled by default as they would not be needed in production. You can enable them in two ways:

1. Edit the two following files and change `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` in the debuginfo section of:

   ```
   /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn-main.repo
   /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn-updates.repo
   ```

   Then run the following command to install the debuginfo for python 2.6:

   ```
   sudo yum install python26-debuginfo
   ```
2. To temporarily enable the same repositories just for the case of the install that you need, you could run the following command on it's own:

   ```
   sudo yum install --enablerepo=amzn-main-debuginfo,amzn-updates-debuginfo python26-debuginfo
   ```

For **Amazon Linux 2** instead either:

1. Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-core.repo` as above before installing
2. Or to run all in one command (as root):

   ```
   yum install --enablerepo=amzn2-core-debuginfo python3-debuginfo
   ```

Comment: Do you have any idea what your options are if you need versions of the debuginfo packages older than what are in the Amazon yum repos? Is there any archive for older Amazon RPMs?